# Facebook Graph API POST video upload source parameter not working

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request, http-post

It works fine with **file_url** on a video file hosted anywhere, but not with my local video file with the **source** parameter

This is my python code for the POST request:

```
import requests

url2 = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v10.0/105868438278259/videos'
myobj2 = {
    'access_token': '****',
    'source': 'file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4', #it's in the same folder
    'title': 'test title 123456',
    'description': 'Video description',
    }

x2 = requests.post(url2, data = myobj2)
print (x2.text)
```

I'm using Facebook Graph API v10, Non-Resumable Upload, the only limitations are:

- Video File have to be less than 1 GB
- Video File have to be less than 20 minutes long

My video is 1 minute long and 5 mb in size, but I receive this response:

```
{"error":{"message":"There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.","type":"OAuthException","code":390,"error_subcode":1363030,"is_transient":true,"error_user_title":"Tiempo de espera agotado al subir el video","error_user_msg":"Se agot\u00f3 el tiempo de espera antes de que se terminara de subir el video. Probablemente se debe a una conexi\u00f3n de red lenta o a que el video que intentas subir es demasiado grande. Vuelve a intentarlo.","fbtrace_id":"AFTgEBhNlaGPyWaGs_RFi-y"}}
```

I have not a low speed connection and my file is not too big according to the limitations

This is the documentation from Facebook Graph API
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/video-api/guides/publishing/?locale=en_US#non-resumable-upload

I tried adding the **content-type: video/mp4** as a parameter too, but it isn't working

What am I missing?

Comment: source should be a file. Not a path. Now you upload a file using the requests api I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Like @WizKid said, it should be a file not just a path, it's not really clear in the facebook documentation how you can add a local file, now it's working like this:

```
url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v10.0/105868438278259/videos'
fp = 'file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4'

files = {'source': open(fp, 'rb')}
payload = {
    'access_token': '****', 
    'title': 'test title 12345667657',
    'description': 'Video description 1',
}

response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=payload, verify=False)
```